# Append multiple dropdown values to URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, drop-down-menu, onchange

I'm trying to do something similar to this:

```
$('#dropdown1').change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).val();
});
```

I need to build a page with 2 dropdown lists and a textbox, and I need the values for each one to be stored and then appended to the URL when the form is submitted.

The URL needs to look similar to this when all options have been selected:

```
http://www.domain.co.uk/search-results/?searchOptions=dropdown1=value1|dropdown2=value2|textarea1=value3
```

I've figured out how to store the values of the dropdowns but I can't seem to append it to the url.. Here's where I got to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getValues() {
    var priceTo = document.form.priceTo.value;
    //alert (priceTo);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //var zip = $('#zip').val();
    var initialURL = 'http://www.domain.co.uk/search-results/?searchOptions=priceto='

    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        window.location.href = initialURL + priceTo
        return false;
    });

});
</script>

<body>

<form id="form" name="form">
    Price:
    <select name="priceTo" id="priceTo" onchange="getValues()">
        <option value="5000">Up to £5,000</option>
        <option value="10000">Up to £10,000</option>
        <option value="20000">Up to £20,000</option>
        <option value="40000">Up to £40,000</option>
        <option value="80000">Up to £80,000</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
```

For some reason this goes to:
http://www.domain.co.uk/search-results/?searchOptions=priceto=[object%20HTMLSelectElement]

EDIT:
I finally got it working on most browsers, including IE8 with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //var zip = $('#zip').val();
    var initialURL = 'http://www.selektvolvocars.co.uk/selekt-search-results/?searchOptions='

    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        window.location.href = initialURL + priceTo.options[priceTo.selectedIndex].value + model.options[model.selectedIndex].value + '%7Czipcode=' +document.getElementById('zip').value + '%7Cproximitydistance=50'
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>
```

For some reason though it doesn't work in IE9... makes no damn sense to me, it just spits out a completely jumbled up URL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your priceTo is the select list. Use the following to get the selected value:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
        window.location.href = initialURL + priceTo.options[priceTo.selectedIndex].value
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks!
*Edit: what would be the equivalent of 'priceTo.options[priceTo.selectedIndex].value' for a textbox?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly:

```
var initialURL = 'http://www.domain.co.uk/search-results/?searchOptions=priceto='    
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
        window.location = initialURL + $("#priceTo").val() + "|" + $("#anyOtherSelects").val();
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

You can remove the rest of the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little helper function which gets the id of a `<select>` or `<input>` element and returns it with its value. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Helper function to return id and value. The id parameter shouldn't have the # sign at its beginning
function getIdVal( id ) {
    return id + "=" + encodeURIComponent( $("#"+id).val() );
}
//run this when the document is loaded and ready
$(document).ready(function() {

    //var zip = $('#zip').val();
    var initialURL = 'http://www.domain.co.uk/search-results/?'

    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
        window.location.href = initialURL + getIdVal( "priceFrom" ) + "|" + getIdVal( "priceTo" );
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

Notes:

- You get the value of the current `<option>` selected in a `<select>` element using `$(...).val()`.
- It is a good programming practice to use encodeURIComponent() for encoding the values just to make sure that no strange character is going to break your convention of using `=` and `|` as record and field separator in the search query URL.